# Ionic2, cordova and offline push notifications without cloud

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

I'm not an expert in cordova or ionic2, so I hope you can help me!

I have a simple question. Is it possible to have local notifications without using some cloud as firebird or ionic messaging cloud?
My app have not to be online to get an alarm from some connected cloud server! But my app has to listen a local server with websocket or something elese and gives pushnotifications on some events.
thx

Comment: You can use local notification plugin.Check this link https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Comment: Yea, i know this plugin and it works great!
But I need this also offline and in background. So I need also a background mode like android service which connects to a websocket server and listen for push notification, noMessage I show a Notification with cordova-plugin-local-notifications.

I'm testing this plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode but I'm not sure if this can do anything I need.